# Are configuration settings replaced when adding an external configuration file?

Tags: tomcat, grails, configuration, configuration-files

I am a bit confused about externalizing configuration settings in grails 2.3.5 when deploying the war to tomcat. Considering I do the following in my applications config.groovy

```
// some grails plugin settings
// some grails spring security settings
def catalinaBase = System.properties.getProperty('catalina.base')
if (!catalinaBase) catalinaBase = '.'   // just in case
def logDirectory = "${catalinaBase}/logs"


environments {
  development {
        //some logging settings
        grails {
            plugin {
                aws {
                    credentials {
                        accessKey = "local"
                        secretKey = "local"
                    }
                    s3 {
                        bucket = "local"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
  }
  production {
    def tomcatConfDir = new File("${System.properties['catalina.home']}/conf")
    grails.config.locations << "file:${tomcatConfDir.canonicalPath}/${appName}-config.groovy"  
  }
}
```

and If I create the following file on the server running tomcat: `/tomcat/conf/myapp-config.groovy`

myapp-config.groovy

```
def env = System.getenv()
log4j = { root->
   // some log settings
}
    grails {
        plugin {
            aws {
                credentials {
                    accessKey = "production"
                    secretKey = "production"
                }
                s3 {
                    bucket = "production"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**Question**

in `/tomcat/conf/myapp-config.groovy` do I need to type the `some grails plugin settings` and `some grails spring security plugins` etc again? My question is that when I add an external file, will the values from my applications config.groovy taken as well? Also, can we use groovy code in the external file? note I've used `def env = System.getenv()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, it's merged. You don't need to repeat yourself. Grails essentially loads your `Config.groovy` then replaces any of the values that are in there with the values found in your external configuration files. It also adds any values that only exist in your external configuration to the "merged" configuration.

As with `Config.groovy` groovy code is also allowed in external configuration files.